# Помогите найти ошибку в коде PYTHON (3.7)

Tags: python

Вот код:

```
wtf1 = input( "Добро пожаловать! Введи, пожалуйста, своё имя: ")
wtf2 = input( "Супер, какие оценки ты хочешь симулировать?" )
wtf3 = [wtf2]
import statistics
print(statistics.mean(int([wtf3])))
```

Должно выдавать среднее арифметическое чисел, которые ввел пользователь.
Нужна эта программа для того, чтобы пользователи могли узнать свой балл, если получат те или иные оценки

Comment: `print(statistics.mean(map(int, wtf2.split())))` ?

Comment: У вас ошибка в значении, передаваемое в `int`. А так, если пишите про какие-то либо ошибки, то добавляйте их описание и желательно вместе с трассой стека

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь применить int к списку, в котором у Вас одна переменная - string.

```
wtf3 = [wtf2]
# после ввода 1 2 3:
wtf3 = ['1 2 3'] # то есть просто строка внутри списка
```

Я бы сделал так

```
import statistics
wtf1 = input( "Добро пожаловать! Введи, пожалуйста, своё имя: ")
wtf2 = list(map(int, input("Супер, какие оценки ты хочешь симулировать?").split()))
#в этой строчке, 
#введенная строка разделяется на символы с помощью split, и затем применяется
# int к каждому элементу с помощью map функции. В результате в списке окажутся числа
print(statistics.mean(wtf2))
```